# PHP $_SESSION on form submit lost

Tags: php

I'm lossing the session when I submit a form, until them I kept loged in my code.

I'm sending the session values through the form in that way, but it does not work at all:

```
<input type='hidden' name='loged' value='".$_SESSION["loged"]."'>
<input type='hidden' name='role' value='".$_SESSION["role"]."'>
```

Is that right?

Thanks you

of course before I get loged, I alredy worte this on the code:

session_start();

Comment: Why do you need to put session data into form inputs? Why can't you just read it from `$_SESSION`?

Comment: to set the value try using "<?php echo $_SESSION['loged']; ?>"

Comment: If you lose the session data, you're most likely doing something *wrong*. Can you post a short example to reproduce what is happening?

Comment: is this part of html code,or php? could you post a little more code?

Comment: Ok, the main problem is that I lost the session when I execute the submit, but not when I execute a link that point the same place... the main reason I need to use the submit is because when I click the link I execute an specific sql query, and when I do the submit I execute the query but passing what I want to look in the query. If I do so passing the parameter through a link in that why index.php?param=value it works well, but when I execute the submit I get loged out...

Answer (score 2):

wrong way, you don't need to submit values already set in session

Comment: But My problem is that when I submit the form I lose the session, but if I do anything else, for example, passing parameters through the URL I kept logged.

Comment: Here it goes: if($_SESSION["logged"] == "yes"  and $_SESSION["role"] == "admin" ){
     

        echo"

     
      <form method='post' action=''>
    <div class='search'>
         <input type='text' style='color:#f65656' name='char' value=''> 
    </div>
    <div class='search_submitbox'>
         <input value='サーチ'  type='submit' id='search'> 
    </div>
    <input type='hidden' name='logged' value='".$_SESSION["logeado"]."'>
    <input type='hidden' name='role' value='".$_SESSION["role"]."'>
    
      </form>";

Comment: Ok, the main problem is that I lost the session when I execute the submit, but not when I execute a link that point the same place... the main reason I need to use the submit is because when I click the link I execute an specific sql query, and when I do the submit I execute the query but passing what I want to look in the query. If I do so passing the parameter through a link in that why index.php?param=value it works well, but when I execute the submit I get loged out...

Comment: 1) remove hidden inputs - 2) add action="your_url" to your <form tag - 3) before you execute search query, check your session values to know if user is allowed - 4) all your scripts must have session_start() to not lose session

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting the form ... if you do a `phpinfo();` you'll see that the inputs have now arrived as value under `$_REQUEST` ...  If you want to access the session variables again, you need to:

- session_start();
- print_r($_SESSION);

You'll see your session vars again.